# How to notate mathematically the $n$ maximum numbers out of $k$ numbers in a set

Tags: notation

I have a set $X =  \{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k\} $

I am struggling with how to write the correct notation to the problem of finding the $n$ maximum numbers out of $k$ numbers.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean the $n$ largest numbers in this set? One simple way to do it would be to order the set so that $x_1 \leq x_2 \leq \dots \leq x_k$. Then the $n$ largest elements of your set are $x_k, x_{k-1}, \dots, x_{k-n+1}$.

Otherwise I would recommend defining your own function. For example you can just define $F_n$ to be the function which maps some set $X$ to a set consisting of the $n$ largest elements of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "correct" notation in cases like this, and you will need to choose your own. I would choose something like $\max_n(X)$ to be the $n$ greatest elements of $X$, as a generalisation of $\max$. But you need to explain to the reader what your notation means.

To formally define $\max_n(\_)$, a function (sort of!) which takes a set as input and returns a set of size $n\in\mathbb{N}$, I might say:

$$\begin{align}X_0&:=\emptyset\\
X_{n+1}&:= X_n\cup\{\max(X\setminus X_n)\} \ \ \ \text{for}\ n\ge0
\end{align} $$

(And notice $\max_1\neq \max$ as $\max(X)\in X$ is an element and $\max_1(X)=\{\max(X)\}$ is a singleton set.)

Answer (score 1):

Either you order the set without loss as $x_1\leq...\leq x_k.$

Otherwise, define the largest elements recursively as:

$$x_{(k)}\equiv \max\{ X\}\\
x_{(j)}\equiv \max \{X\setminus \cup_{m=j+1}^k \{x_{(m)}\}\},j\in \{1,...,k-1\},$$

and your $n$ largest numbers are then $x_{(k-n+1)},...,x_{(k)}.$